# Resize image file retaining jpg Exif information

Tags: java, parameters, image-resizing, exif

I would like to copy images with all the Exif image data also copied.

I have a Java app that reads in a jpg into an image object, resizes it, and then writes the image object to a jpg file in another folder.

The problem is that it loses all that nice image information (camera, date, and so on).
Any ideas?

Comment: No - what is "exif" ?  I never heard of that.

Comment: Yes - that is what I need - Wikipedia: Exif data are embedded within the image file itself. While many recent image manipulation programs recognize and preserve Exif data when writing to a modified image, this is not the case for most older programs.

Comment: I found http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/  -  metadata extraction in java.  I will try this package and let you know...

Comment: No, that is just for extracting/reading.  I now found this: package org.apache.sanselan

Answer (score 0):

Though intended for Android, this solution is in Java and should be helpful for copying all the EXIF metadata from one file to another:

http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/copying-exif-metadata-using-sanselan/

Note that Sanselan has of late been rebranded Commons Imaging and can be found here:

http://commons.apache.org/imaging/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use image IO like this:

```
try (ImageInputStream inputStream = new FileImageInputStream(new File("Landscape_3.jpg"))) {
        Iterator<ImageReader> readerIterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(inputStream);
        ImageReader reader = readerIterator.next();
        reader.setInput(inputStream);
        Iterator<IIOImage> imageIterator = reader.readAll(null);
        IIOImage image = imageIterator.next();

        BufferedImage srcImage = (BufferedImage) image.getRenderedImage();
        AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(0.5, 0.5), AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
        BufferedImage resultImage = scaleOp.createCompatibleDestImage(srcImage, null);
        resultImage = scaleOp.filter(srcImage, resultImage);
        image.setRenderedImage(resultImage);

        ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWriter(reader);
        try (ImageOutputStream outputStream = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("Landscape_3_preserve_exif.jpg"))) {
            writer.setOutput(outputStream);
            writer.write(image);
        }
        try (ImageOutputStream outputStream = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("Landscape_3_discard_exif.jpg"))) {
            writer.setOutput(outputStream);
            writer.write(image.getRenderedImage());
        }
    }
```

Pitfalls:

- It's slow as image io framework in general
- It fails inexplicably for some rare images. Example (javax.imageio.IIOException: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xe2)
- It requires using the same color model for source and target images. As a result you cannot use bilinear or bicubic interpolation